# Print sorbet flavors

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation

You're working for a restaurant and they're asking you to generate the sorbet menu.

Provide a script printing every possible sorbet duos from a given list of flavors.

Don't print recipes with twice the same flavor (no "Chocolate Chocolate"), and don't print twice the same recipe (if you print "Vanilla Chocolate", don't print "Chocolate Vanilla", or vice-versa).

The flavors are:

```
FLAVORS = [
    "Banana",
    "Chocolate",
    "Lemon",
    "Pistachio",
    "Raspberry",
    "Strawberry",
    "Vanilla",
]
```

**> My code is here:**

```
FLAVORS = [
    "Banana",
    "Chocolate",
    "Lemon",
    "Pistachio",
    "Raspberry",
    "Strawberry",
    "Vanilla",
]

for i in FLAVORS:
    if len(FLAVORS) >= 2:
        for g in FLAVORS:
            if g==i:
                continue
            else:
                print(f"{i}, {g}")
        FLAVORS.remove(g)
```

**the result I got:**

```
Banana, Chocolate
Banana, Lemon
Banana, Pistachio
Banana, Raspberry
Banana, Strawberry
Banana, Vanilla
Chocolate, Banana
Chocolate, Lemon
Chocolate, Pistachio
Chocolate, Raspberry
Chocolate, Strawberry
Lemon, Banana
Lemon, Chocolate
Lemon, Pistachio
Lemon, Raspberry
Pistachio, Banana
Pistachio, Chocolate
Pistachio, Lemon
```

**The question is:**
Why not proposing Pistachio, Raspberry (or Raspberry, Pistachio)?

Comment: Because you remove entries while iterating over the list. Try it on [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html) to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
import itertools
for f in itertools.permutations(FLAVORS, 2):
    if f[0] <= f[-1]:
        print(f)
```

It will output:

```
('Banana', 'Chocolate')
('Banana', 'Lemon')
('Banana', 'Pistachio')
('Banana', 'Raspberry')
('Banana', 'Strawberry')
('Banana', 'Vanilla')
('Chocolate', 'Lemon')
('Chocolate', 'Pistachio')
('Chocolate', 'Raspberry')
('Chocolate', 'Strawberry')
('Chocolate', 'Vanilla')
('Lemon', 'Pistachio')
('Lemon', 'Raspberry')
('Lemon', 'Strawberry')
('Lemon', 'Vanilla')
('Pistachio', 'Raspberry')
('Pistachio', 'Strawberry')
('Pistachio', 'Vanilla')
('Raspberry', 'Strawberry')
('Raspberry', 'Vanilla')
('Strawberry', 'Vanilla')
```

> The condition `f[0] <= f[-1]`  works because reversing the permutation
> would always flip the relation between first and last element!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the results I found a pattern, the combination is of itself and everything except itself and the flavors prior to it.
I think this code is probably the simplest.

```
FLAVORS = [
    "Banana",
    "Chocolate",
    "Lemon",
    "Pistachio",
    "Raspberry",
    "Strawberry",
    "Vanilla",
]

for i in FLAVORS:
    for j in range(FLAVORS.index(i)+1,len(FLAVORS)):
        print(i + ", " + FLAVORS[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are removing elements in the loop, while itering on the same list.

To illustrate why it's a problem, let's check this code :

```py
FLAVORS = [
    "Banana",
    "Chocolate",
    "Lemon",
    "Pistachio",
    "Raspberry",
    "Strawberry",
    "Vanilla",
]
        
        
for i in FLAVORS:
    print(i)
    FLAVORS.remove(i)
```

you would expect to print all the flavors in the list but instead you get :

```
Banana
Lemon
Raspberry
Vanilla
```

Try this :

```py
    FLAVORS = [
    "Banana",
    "Chocolate",
    "Lemon",
    "Pistachio",
    "Raspberry",
    "Strawberry",
    "Vanilla",
]

already_tried = []

for i in FLAVORS:
    if len(FLAVORS) >= 1:
        for g in FLAVORS:
            if g==i or g in already_tried:
                continue
            else:
                print(f"{i}, {g}")
        already_tried.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution based on other answers (they didn't work as expected for me). Only thing they were missing is appending i variable as well to the already_tried list.

```
  already_tried = []

for i in FLAVORS:
    if len(FLAVORS) >= 1:
        for g in FLAVORS:
            if g == i or g in already_tried:
                continue
            else:
                print(f'{g}, {i}')
            already_tried.append(g and i)
```